# Number of values of determinant under restricted entry of elements.

Tags: matrices, combinations, determinant

"If each entry of a 3×3 determinant is either 1 or -1 then find the possible values of such a determinant".

I have tried a comparitively easier variation of the above problem that is instead of +1 and -1 the entries can be +1 and 0, and it was easier because if i take a triplet(triplet here implies the product of 3 elements formed when expanding determinant) and it is 0 then we can say that all of them arent non zero and since each element of determinant occurs in 2 triplets, we can easily analyze to get values as -2,+2,-1,+1,0.

But when dealing with the above shown version of this problem, it is taking a lot of cases to be dealt with, at a point i am becoming unclear, i tried the same approach as the below problem in the above problem like:

|a b c |
|d e f |   = det.
|g h i |

aei+bfg+cdh-(gec+hfa+idb)

Each triplet = +1 or -1
If triplet= 1 then either all 3 are 1 or 2 are -1 and one is 1.
But when i try to analyze it with the other 3 triplets in which the 3 elements repeat for ex: aei let a=e=-1 and i=1 then analyzing with gec,idb,hfa is becoming very complicated.

I tried searching for similar alliterations to this question on this site for answer but did not found what i exactly needed.
Can anyone share an algorithm, process or if possible just the thinking process to solve above questions.
(I found a nice way to find number of equivalence relations on a set which thus lead me here again)

Comment: Please use mathjax in order to format your question

Comment: I'd start with the rule of Sarrus, which tells you that you can get at most the 13 values between -6 and 6. Also, Laplace expansion might give you something with a recursive flair. Also, recall the transformations that don't change the determinant and try to use symmetries.

Comment: Since the determinant is negated by swapping two rows, it suffices to investigate which nonnegative values are possible. As the determinant is the sum of six odd numbers (each of which is equal to $\pm1$), it must be even. Hence the only candidates are $0,2,4$ and $6$. It should be easy to construct examples with determinants $0,2$ or $4$. The only pending case is $6$.

Comment: The great british mathematician J.W.S. Cassels wrote as epigraph in one of his books on elliptic curves, something like this: "**Integer numbers, the most basic but also the most intractable of mathematical material**".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $M=\begin{vmatrix} a_1&a_2&a_3\\a_4&a_5&a_6\\a_7&a_8&a_9\end{vmatrix}=(a_1a_5a_9+a_2a_6a_7+a_3a_4a_8)-(a_1a_6a_8+a_2a_4a_9+a_3a_5a_7)$ so in this problem we have
$$M=(\pm1\pm1\pm1)-(\pm1\pm1\pm1)$$ each of the two numbers in brackets can be equal to $(\pm1\pm3)$ so $$M=(\pm1,\pm3)-(\pm1,\pm3)\in\{0,\pm2,\pm4,\pm6\}$$
$M=0$ when two lines are equal.

$M=4$ when $a_1=a_2=a_3=a_4=a_7=a_8=1$ and $a_5=a_6=a_9=-1$ (interchanging two lines we get $M=-4$).

To have $M=2\text { or } 6$ we need $$159+267+348=b \text { and } 168+249+357=-b \text { with b=1,3, respectively. }$$
We can put $a_1=1$ from which we get in both cases
$$9=-37,\space5=-24,\space8=-27,\space6=-34$$
Then $$M=\begin{vmatrix} 1&a_2&a_3\\a_4&-a_2a_4&-a_3a_4\\a_7&-a_2a_7&-a_3a_7\end{vmatrix}=a_4a_7\begin{vmatrix} 1&a_2&a_3\\1&-a_2&-a_3\\1&-a_2&-a_3\end{vmatrix}=0,\text { contradiction. }$$
**So $2$ and $6$ never appear and the only possible values of determinants are $0$ and $\pm4.$**